# ConfigMap mounted on Persistent Volume Claims

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

In my deployment, I would like to use a Persistent Volume Claim in combination with a config map mount. For example, I'd like the following:

```
volumeMounts:
    - name: py-js-storage
        mountPath: /home/python
    - name: my-config
        mountPath: /home/python/my-config.properties
        subPath: my-config.properties
        readOnly: true
...
    volumes:
    - name: py-storage
    {{- if .Values.py.persistence.enabled }}
        persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: python-storage
    {{- else }}
        emptyDir: {}
    {{- end }}
```

Is this a possible and viable way to go? Is there any better way to approach such situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you didn't give your use case, my answer will be based on if it is possible or not. In fact: **Yes, it is.**

I'm supposing you wish mount file from a `configMap` in a mount point that already contains other files, and your approach to use `subPath` is correct!

When you need to mount different volumes on the same path, you need specify `subPath` or the content of the original dir will be **hidden**.

In other words, if you want to keep both files (from the mount point **and** from configMap) you **must** use `subPath`.

To illustrate this, I've tested with the deployment code below. There I mount the hostPath `/mnt` that contains a file called `filesystem-file.txt` in my pod and the file `/mnt/configmap-file.txt` from my configmap `test-pd-plus-cfgmap`:

> **Note:** I'm using Kubernetes 1.18.1

**Configmap:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-pd-plus-cfgmap
data:
  file-from-cfgmap: file data
```

**Deployment:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-pv
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-pv
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-pv
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /mnt
          name: task-pv-storage
        - mountPath: /mnt/configmap-file.txt
          subPath: configmap-file.txt
          name: task-cm-file
      volumes:
        - name: task-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: task-pv-claim
        - name: task-cm-file
          configMap:
            name: test-pd-plus-cfgmap
```

As a result of the deployment, you can see the follow content in `/mnt` of the pod:

```
$ kubectl exec test-pv-5bcb54bd46-q2xwm -- ls /mnt
configmap-file.txt
filesystem-file.txt
```

You could check this github [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23748) with the same discussion.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) you could read a little more about volumes `subPath`.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with the following approach.

In your **deployment.yaml** template file you can configure:

```
...
{{- if .Values.volumeMounts }}
        volumeMounts:
{{- range .Values.volumeMounts }}
        - name: {{ .name }}
          mountPath: {{ .mountPath }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
...
{{- if .Values.volumeMounts }}
      volumes:
{{- range .Values.volumeMounts }}
      - name: {{ .name }}
{{ toYaml .volumeSource | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

And your **values.yaml** file you can define any volume sources:

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: volume-mount-1
    mountPath: /var/data
    volumeSource:
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc-name
  - name: volume-mount-2
    mountPath: /var/config
    volumeSource:
      configMap:
        name: config-map-name
```

In this way, you don't have to worry about the source of the volume. You can add any kind of sources in your values.yaml file and you don't have to update the **deployment.yaml** template.

Hope this helps!